# Making postgresql logs in JSON format

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 9.5 on ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any way in postgresql so that it's logs can be stored in JSON format ?

I need to send it to elasticsearch, that's why I need to make postgresql logs in JSON format.

I followed this [tutorial](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-logs-json.markdown/), but did not quite understood that what and where it was asking me to make changes in the conf file.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL listens to their community and your voice is heard !

PostgreSQL 15 beta has been released on May 15th, 2022. **PostgreSQL version 15** now supports the `jsonlog` logging format which is to be released in third quarter of 2022 .

You have to make the below change in the `postgresql.conf` file

> log_destination = 'jsonlog'

The log output will be written to  a file, making it the third type of destination of this kind, after `stderr` and `csvlog`.

You can send these generated json logs to elasticsearch or any application for further log aggergations.

Check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-beta-1-released-2453/) for more info

**Update:** PostgreSQL `v15` is out now. You can now explore them [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DESTINATION)

Comment: #v15 has been released confirming the good news!

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DESTINATION

Comment: @plmk thanks for confirming. Will update in the answer

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL self doesn't support any other formats than plain text and CSV. When you need other formats, then you need to get somewhere (or write by self) special extension that is able to touch log API and format and push PostgreSQL logs. One extension was developed by Michael and it is described in mentioned link. Here is link to source code: https://github.com/michaelpq/pg_plugins/tree/master/jsonlog . You have to compile this extension like any other (PostgreSQL extension) - code is in C language, and then you can use it.

Comment: Are there any instructions on how one would compile and install an extension? I've never done this before.

Comment: It depends on platform - it is easy on Linux and not simple on Windows. For Linux - install develop PostgreSQL package, then `make USE_PGXS=1; su - ; make install USE_PGXS=1`

Comment: Actually, just opened a new question with a lot more context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144194/how-to-build-postgres-jsonlog-in-multi-stage-docker-container. Tried `make install`, but didn't work. I'll try `USE_PGXS=1`. Thanks!

Comment: Hm. No, same. I keep getting `Unrecognized key word: "jsonlog"`.

Answer (score 0):

As I am understanding your problem statement is you want to push postgresql logs to Elasticsearch.

For this I would recommend to use [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat) where you can simple enable the [PostgresSQL module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-postgresql.html) and set the log path. Filebeat start reading logs file and push to Elasticsearch.

You can visualize your data from kibana with readymade dashboard. It is simple plug and play.