# How to build Postgres jsonlog in multi-stage Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a multi-stage Docker container where I build jsonlog.

```
# Build stage
FROM postgres:11.5 AS build-env
ADD . /jsonlog
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libkrb5-dev libssl-dev libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-all
RUN cd /jsonlog && make install
# Used find to see where the output files are being installed
# RUN find / -name "*json*"

# Final stage
FROM postgres:11.5-alpine
COPY --from=build-env /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/bitcode/jsonlog/jsonlog.bc /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/bitcode/jsonlog/jsonlog.bc
COPY --from=build-env /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/bitcode/jsonlog.index.bc /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/bitcode/jsonlog.index.bc
COPY --from=build-env /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/jsonlog.so /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/jsonlog.so
```

The `docker build` seems to be okay. However, when I do a `docker run`, I get this error.

```
LOG:  invalid value for parameter "log_destination": "jsonlog"
DETAIL:  Unrecognized key word: "jsonlog".
FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

The jsonlog code comes from this repo, https://github.com/michaelpq/pg_plugins/tree/master/jsonlog, which I cloned. I mount just the `jsonlog` directory into the build container.

The `postgresql.conf` is vanilla, except for these lines.

```
log_destination = 'jsonlog'
logging_collector = on
shared_preload_libraries = 'jsonlog'
```

The reason for doing a multi-stage container is to get rid of build dependencies and have a smaller container. I'd like to run `postgres:11.5-alpine`, but I also get errors with the `postgres:11.5` image.

**Update**

I tried getting rid of the multi-stage and just keeping everything in 1 container like this.

```
FROM postgres:11.5
ADD . /jsonlog
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libkrb5-dev libssl-dev libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-all
RUN cd /jsonlog && make install
```

But that results in the exact `Unrecognized key word: "jsonlog"` error.

Also, also, I tried building in a Postgres 9.5 container and the same thing happens.

Comment: Well at least don't mix alpine and no-alpine images. glibc and musl don't mix well.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, that's why I tried keeping everything in just the debian image, but still doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that you simply leave log_destination as 'stderr' and the jsonlog plugin overrides the log_hook in PG and, magically, logs start coming out in JSON format.

So the only change needed, AFAIK, is:

shared_preload_libraries = 'jsonlog'